# Tailwindcss changes vertical alignment of an inline element

Tags: css, tailwind-css, antd, vertical-alignment

I use tailwindcss with antd to develop my website.

The following two code sandboxes shows the same antd component with and without tailwindcss

- https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-collapse-u1diyl
- https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-collapse-with-tailwind-ubl1de

You can see that in the first sandbox, the arrow and text are vertically aligned while in the second one they are not. The only change in the second sandbox is that I included tailwindcss.

However in chrome's inspector, both arrow elements have the same computed css except for tab size (which I don't think would affect the vertical alignment).

| Vertially Aligned | Not Vertically Aligned |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

Anyone knows why tailwindcss changes the vertical alignment of the arrow and how to fix it? I would like the arrow and text elements to be vertically aligned.

Comment: Hi there, you'll get better results on SO if you provide a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](Minimal, Reproducible Example) as opposed to sharing links to entire components on other sites, but it sounds like Tailwind's CSS reset is removing some of the styles that make the original component align that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by adding this in the tailwind.config.js

```
 corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
```

Comment: Yeah, this would fix it. But I'm wondering what exactly in the preflight changes the behavior